# How to know file changed before uploading to a server

Tags: php, file, yii

I am a yii developer, when I do any changes I need to know which file I changed to upload to Bluehost server.

Is there any software will help me to do that, because every time I have to remember which file I changed

Comment: use Git and run deployment scripts to update server

Comment: Thank you @DhavalChheda for your answer, and that's exactly what I was looking for a long time

Comment: you're welcome @Mahdi Miad